# What was piloting the decoy ship?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

In the fifth episode of *Obi-Wan Kenobi*, a group of Rebels and refugees

> escape Vader by using one of their freighter ships as a decoy that attempts to fly away. Vader pulls it back to the ground, while the other ship leaves during his distraction.

Who/what was piloting the ship? Did somebody stay behind and pilot the ship? Was it autopilot? Or perhaps a droid?

Comment: It was a Tesla model with self-driving capability.  That was the real reason it crashed.

Comment: I had the same question. Notably, the imperial forces don't look for a pilot, which I'd expect them to do even if it was a droid. Given, Vader was distracted.

Comment: "*He uses the Force to grab Roken's freighter, preventing the ship from ascending and forcing it to the ground. He rips the ship apart only to find that it is an empty decoy.*" - Per wookieepedia